# Eliminating file tag from file at schema Level in Biztalk

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-schemas

I have sequential file where data is as below,

```
101 name1 ABC 1234
102 name2 ABC 1234
103 name3 ABC 1234
104 name4 ABC 1234
```

My schema passes though a pipeline.

Here my concern is, I want to eliminate (not to read from file / Ignore while parsing) tag 103 at schema level.

Can some one tell, how shall I manage it?

Just want to know the property if any at schema level or simple way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't ignore the tag, you have to have it in your schema otherwise it will fail to parse.

However once you have read the file into an XML format in your pipeline you can then map it and exclude the contents of that tag in your mapping.  You can have this map on the receive port so the message that gets published to the message box does not have the 103 tag.